# Including graphics

Tags: graphics

The following code does not produce the desired image:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth]%
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}%

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,natwidth=440,natheight=600]
    {Cauchy.jpg}
\vspace{-10pt}%
\end{wrapfigure}

{\small
      \begin{spacing}{0.8}
\lipsum[1]
\vspace{-10pt}%
\end{spacing}
}
\end{tcolorbox}%
\end{document}
```

Before I updated MikTeX everything worked perfect. Now there is a blank spot where Cauchy's face should be. I have checked the file `Cauchy.jpg` (using `\includegraphics`) and it worked. I am using `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have problems with use of the `\includegraphics` options `natwidth=440,natheight=600`. if you will remove them, image will apear:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth]%
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}%

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    %{Cauchy.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}
\small
\begin{spacing}{0.8}
\lipsum[1]
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\end{spacing}
\end{tcolorbox}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

(if you like to have larger image, than increase the width of `wrapfigure` environment.